# Unable to load 'en' from spacy in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I run the following lines of code in a jupyter notebook:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

And get following error:

```
Warning: no model found for 'en_default'

Only loading the 'en' tokenizer.
```

I am using python 3.5.3, spacy 1.9.0, and jupyter notebook 5.0.0.
I downloaded spacy using `conda install spacy` and `python3 spacy install en`.
I am able to import spacy and load 'en' from my terminal but not from a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Can you confirm it's the same Python interpreter, because I doubt it. Type `import sys; sys.executable` for both your default Python and Jupyer Python. If it's not the same Python install, well, then the issue is clear. If it is, then... well it'll be more complicated.

Comment: My terminal returns '//anaconda/bin/python3' and jupyter returns '//anaconda/envs/capstone/bin/python'

Comment: That sounds like they may be the same interpreter but not guaranteed, since "envs" is often a symbolic link (if it works like `/usr/bin/env`). Do you have Bash, can you check `file $file` for both?

Comment: `//anaconda/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` and `//anaconda/envs/capstone/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Comment: So then they are not the same interpreter. I would just reinstall `Spacy` or `en` in the Jupyter interpreter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the answer in your comments, it seems fairly clear that the two Python interpreters for Jupyter and your system Python are not the same, and therefore likely do not have shared libraries between them.

I would recommend re-running the installation or just specifically installation the `en` tool in the correct Spacy. Replace the path with the full path to the file, if the above is not the full path.

```
//anaconda/envs/capstone/bin/python -m spacy download
```

That **should** be enough. Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: It worked but with this syntax: `//anaconda/envs/capstone/bin/python -m spacy download en`. Otherwise it would throw error.

Answer (score 4):

You can also download en language model in the jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m spacy download en
```